# ActiveRecord and using reject method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, enumeration

I have a model that fetches all the games from a particular city. When I get those games I want to filter them and I would like to use the `reject` method, but I'm running into an error I'm trying to understand.

```
# STEP 1 - Model
class Matches < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total_losses(cities)
    reject{ |a| cities.include?(a.winner) }.count
  end
end

# STEP 2 - Controller
@games = Matches.find_matches_by("Toronto")
# GOOD! - Returns ActiveRecord::Relation

# STEP 3 - View
cities = ["Toronto", "NYC"]
@games.total_losses(cities)
# FAIL - undefined method reject for #<Class:0x00000101ee6360>

# STEP 3 - View
cities = ["Toronto", "NYC"]
@games.reject{ |a| cities.include?(a.winner) }.count
# PASSES - it returns a number.
```

Why does `reject` fail in my model but not in my view ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is the object you are calling `reject` on. In the view, `@games` is an array of Active Record objects, so calling `@games.reject` uses `Array#reject`. In your model, you're calling `reject` on `self` in a class method, meaning it's attempting to call `Matches.reject`, which doesn't exist. You need to fetch records first, like this:

```
def self.total_losses(cities)
  all.reject { |a| cities.include(a.winner) }.count
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I noticed your blog has a good article explaining the use of `self`. [Self in Ruby](http://jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby) Good read for anyone else who is interested. One more question -- Just curious if you think this logic makes sense to reside in the Model or should it go somewhere else?

Comment: @neuone - Yes, it makes sense in the model. It'd be more efficient to look up records with conditions rather than fetching all of them and filtering them after the fact, however.