# Get unsaved associations from inside the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I access unsaved associations from inside a model method? For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def comment_dates
    comments.pluck(:created_at).sort
  end
end
```

The `comments` method called inside a model method returns just already saved associations. When I call the method from the object, e.g. `post.comments` it returns both saved and unsaved associations.

How can I access saved and unsaved associations from inside a model method? I need this to do some complex validation including associations.

Comment: Actually is not that comments return just persisted comments. Is that when I call any method that touches the database, such as `pluck`, it ignores the unpersisted comments. So I must avoid ActiveRecord methods to deal with that objects.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "ignores the unpersisted comments". If model (`Comment` in your example) it's `created_at` should be empty (well, it's not persisted, so it has no creation date). When in your model you have `comments.pluck(:created_at).sort` it actually performs the query, but you can replace it with `comments.map(&:created_at).sort` so it operates on current `Comment` objects. I'll update the answer if this is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def comment_dates
    comments.pluck(:created_at).sort
  end

  def comments_dates_no_query
    comments.map(&:created_at).sort
  end

  def unsaved_comments
    comments.reject(&:persisted?)
  end

  def saved_comments
    comments.select(&:persisted?)
  end
end
```

You can us it like

```
post.saved_comments
```

or

```
post.unsaved_comments
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you sure that comments.reject(&:persisted?) returns anything?

Comment: @ppascualv - Yes, quick googling shows other use cases: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029598/rails-reject-turns-type-activerecordrelation-into-type-array), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207424/activerecord-and-using-reject-method). Hope that proves it works! Let me know if I'm missing something, though!

Comment: In my experience, if the e.g., Post model hasn't been persisted, then unpersisted association members are not available through the #comments method. I've found that you can only get to them by using Array methods like comments.to_a or comments.find.

Comment: This saved my life. I cant thank you enough for this :D